# PHP - Creating MySQL database and user - code not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing an application where multi-tenancy is not suitable. So my plan is to create different MySQL databases and users for each client account. I am having problems, if you can see what's wrong with my code that would be great - I am not getting any errors, but **the database/user is not being added**.

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost";
$pdo = new PDO($dsn,"REMOVED","REMOVED"); // I removed the login.

$username = 'testing';
$password = 'password';
$dbname   = 'test_table'; 

//Creation of user
$STH = $pdo->prepare("CREATE USER `:username` @'%' IDENTIFIED BY `:password`;");
$STH->execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => $password));

//Creation of database "new_db"
$STH = $pdo->prepare("CREATE DATABASE `:dbname`;");
$STH->execute(array(':dbname' => $dbname));

//Adding all privileges on our newly created database
 $STH = $pdo->prepare("GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on `:dbname`.* TO `:username`@'%';");
 $STH->execute(array(':dbname' => $dbname,':username' => $username));
```

Comment: does your "removed" user have privileges to CREATE USER, CREATE DATABASE, GRANT operations ?

Comment: I am using the user that cPanel creates, I am sure that this user has the permissions.

Comment: I don't see the error testing/handling code in your snippet, are you sure it performs its duty correctly?

Comment: What is the output of your executes? They will return false on failure:  http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: @jchapa I am unsure of how to capture the status of the PDO execute.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you said you were using cPanel. Check phpMyAdmin to see if you can create users. If the tab is available then your code should work as expected. If you don't see if then you can check your configuration options in the phpMyAdmin config.inc.php file. I'm an uncertain if the issue resides with cPanel or phpMyAdmin. As for your code, it works 100% on XAMPP running on Windows so the problem lies elsewhere. Sorry I couldn't give a definitive answer!

Comment: Thank's for letting me know the code works! I am going to start examining permissions issues.